# Unable to Send array as a parameter of form

Tags: jquery

I have created a hidden form and trying to add some other input field on ajax success and then later trying to submit this form. However, appending array into field is not going right.

```
success : function(resp) {
   $('#checkout').append('<input type="text" name="subtotal" value="'+resp.data.subTotal+'" />');
   $('#checkout').append('<input type="text" name="tax" value="'+resp.data.tax+'" />');
   $('#checkout').append('<input type="text" name="times" value="'+resp.data.times+'" />');
}
```

Doing so, input field times becomes like

```
<input type="text" name="times" value="[{"start_date":"2019-06-10","end_date":"2019-06-10","start_time":"08:00:00","end_time":"09:00:00"},{"start_date":"2019-06-11","end_date":"2019-06-11","start_time":"08:00:00","end_time":"09:00:00"},{"start_date":"2019-06-12","end_date":"2019-06-12","start_time":"08:00:00","end_time":"09:00:00"}]"
```

response looks like

```
{"status":"200","data":{"times":[{"start_date":"2019-06-10","end_date":"2019-06-10","start_time":"08:00:00","end_time":"09:00:00"},{"start_date":"2019-06-11","end_date":"2019-06-11","start_time":"08:00:00","end_time":"09:00:00"},{"start_date":"2019-06-12","end_date":"2019-06-12","start_time":"08:00:00","end_time":"09:00:00"}],"subTotal":300,"tax":24}}
```

And when I submit this form, it is not sending times value.

> print_r($_POST)

```
Array
(
  [_token] => x8THCiWyxRXnb9T3mKI3ae8XzfKwHicW1SbwBGXS
  [subtotal] => 300
  [tax] => 24
  [times] => [{
)
```

I want to sent those times values to the server either this or that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put the json string within single quote [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25bohfz7/)

```
$('#checkout').append('<input type="text" id="times" name="times" value=\'' + JSON.stringify(resp.data.times) + '\' />');
```

Answer (score 2):

inside your success response stringify JSON data :

```
 success : function(resp) {
                   let times=JSON.stringify(resp.data.times);

                   $('#checkout').append('<input type="text" name="times" value="'+times+'" />');

}
```

and decode at server side :

```
 $posted_data = json_decode($_POST['times'], true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The values of input elements can only be strings, so you'll need to serialize your object first, e.g. into JSON:

```
$('#checkout')
    .append('<input type="text" name="times" value="'
        + JSON.stringify(resp.data.times)
        + '" />');
```